# Common Language Function Chart

Tags: javascript, php, python, css

I am in group of teachers getting ready to teach Computer Science next year to high schoolers who have most likely never programmed before. We were looking for a quick reference chart that lists the same functions across several languages. We are using python, javascript, php, css, and html. We go in depth on python and just touch the surface of the others so we wanted to find a chart that would compare the functions in pythons to other languages for quick reference as students begin programming.

EX.
Nesting 
Python - Indentation          Javascript - "{}"

End line
Python - colon after function, otherwise nothing       Javascript - nothing after function,
otherwise semicolon

If anybody has a resource like this we would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You are probably looking for something like this: http://hyperpolyglot.org/scripting

Comment: Just google for "cheat sheets" on any programming language - it should turn up lots.

Answer (score 2):

If you are teaching Computer Science then you really shouldn't be concerned with the syntax of the language that you are teaching with. Computer Science is programming language independent. I do agree that Python is a great language to use for learning programming concepts I feel you should probably concentrate more on problem solving using programming as a tool.

For example, find a task that the students normally do manually or a task that is very time consuming and see how the students would use programming to help make those tasks easier, automated, or just less time consuming.

Computer Science is about more than just programming, and you would do your students great justice if you approached it with that attitude.

Comment: We do far more than just programming which is why we are looking for the cheat sheet. Instead of getting bogged down in syntax we want the focus to be on the concepts being taught so anything we can do to help them move more quickly through the actual programming is helpful. Additionally we were given our course syllabus and we are not able to ignore parts of the curriculum which means that regardless of how we feel about a topic's place in computer science, we still have to teach it.

Comment: That's good to hear. If the course curriculum requires you to teach x, y, and z languages then I would pick one simple project in each language that best demonstrates the languages strengths. For example although you can build a website in python, more often php, Javascript, and html/xhtml will be used. I would suggest analyzing the standard "Hello World" examples for each language if you want to get an understanding of python x = java x and so on. Since the setup and execution of programs of different languages can be one of the more difficult parts of learning a new language.